# Need to understand how list append() method works with multidimensional list

Tags: python, list

If I want to make a multidimensional list in python (5x5 list for example), this is the *correct* code for it (the O is just a sample placeholder for anything):

```
2dlist = []
for x in range(0,5):
  2dlist.append(['O'] * 5)
```

However, what exactly does the ['O'] * 5 mean here? Because, looking at this, I would assume that the list turns out like this for the first iteration of the loop:

```
[['O'], ['O'], ['O'], ['O'], ['O']]
```

In reality the list would turn out like this in the first iteration of the loop (which is correct):

```
[['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']]
```

Why?

Comment: Multiplying a list by an integer e.g. `['O'] * 3`, is roughly equivalent to `['O'] + ['O'] + ['O']`

Comment: It's appending 5 sublists to `2dlist` (which is an invalid variable name in Python BTW) 5 times — so a square list of lists. You can also use `range(5)` instead of `range(0,5)` because a starting value of `0` is the default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multplying a `list` by an `int` multiplies the contents of the list by said `int`.
For example:

```py
a = [1,2] * 3
print(a)

>>> [1,2,1,2,1,2]
```

This is why in your example when you append `['O'] * 5` to the list you are appending `['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']` to `2dlist`.